# Wait for function to finish to do something else node.js formidable

Tags: javascript, node.js, ecmascript-6, promise, formidable

so my issue here is that the console.log()  at the end of the code always prints before the parse for the formidable form is finish and i dont know how to avoid this

```
exports.scrape =  (req,res) => {

let form = new formidable.IncomingForm();
form.keepExtensions = true;

 form.parse(req, (err, fields, files) => {
    if (err) {
        return res.status(400).json({
            error: 'Image could not be uploaded'
        });
    }
    const { endpoint } = fields;
    if (!endpoint ) {
        return res.status(400).json({
            error: 'All fields are required'
        });
    }
    if (files.file) {
     
        if (files.file.size > 1000000) {
            return res.status(400).json({
                error: 'Image should be less than 1mb in size'
            });
        }
        var oldPath = files.file.path;
        console.log(oldPath);
        var newPath = path.join(__dirname, '../src/files/csv')
            + '/'+files.file.name
         var rawData = fs.readFileSync(oldPath)
  
        fs.writeFile(newPath, rawData, function(err){
            if(err) console.log(err)
            return console.log(newPath);
        })
    
    }

})
```

console.log("test!");
}

And then when the parse is complete make another action bc i need the file being created to later use it in another script that will be initialized when the parse is over, that would bere where the console.log("test!") is

Comment: What does this have to do with Java? You do know that Java and JavaScript are two entirely different languages, right?

Comment: yes i now, thanks, ive edited the tag now

Comment: You want to declare your function as async and await what take some time to execute.

Comment: Do the extra stuff here: `console.log(newPath)`

Answer (score -1):

Get a basic understanding of how callbacks work. Then you realize that putting console.log at the bottom is not chronologically the end.